# partitionning additional disks as LVM with cloud-init

Tags: lvm, cloud-init, terraform

I'm using terraform and cloud-init to setup new VMs.
I want to have additional disks setup and mounted in the new VM, with XFS partitions on top of LVM.
Right now the only way I've found that allows me to do that is with this:

```
    runcmd:
      - [ sgdisk, -e, /dev/sdb ]
      - [ sgdisk, -e, /dev/sdc ]
      - [ partprobe ]
      - [ parted, -s, /dev/sdb, unit, mib, mkpart, primary, '1', "100%" ]
      - [ parted, -s, /dev/sdc, unit, mib, mkpart, primary, '1', "100%" ]
      - [ parted, -s, /dev/sdb, set, "1", lvm, "on" ]
      - [ parted, -s, /dev/sdc, set, "1", lvm, "on" ]
      - [ pvcreate, /dev/sdb1 ]
      - [ pvcreate, /dev/sdc1 ]
      - [ vgcreate, u01, /dev/sdb1]
      - [ vgcreate, u02, /dev/sdc1]
      - [ lvcreate, -l, "100%FREE", -n, oradata, u01]
      - [ lvcreate, -l, "100%FREE", -n, backup, u02]
      - [ mkfs.xfs, /dev/mapper/u01-oradata ]
      - [ mkfs.xfs, /dev/mapper/u02-backup ]
      - [ mount, -a ]
```

Is there any way I can use the disk_setup/fs_setup for this?